# ASP.NET MVC application crashes on IIS 7.5 but not on development notebook

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, iis, crash

I'm having a hard time finding out why my ASP.NET MVC 4.0 (.NET framework version 4.5) application crashes on one machine and runs nicely on another one. Both machines are 64 bit Windows7 pc's. Then development machine runs Visual Studio 2015, the other one IIS 7.5.

This is what I get when I try to browser the application on the IIS machine:
[image]

I've checked the file permissions of the website folder in `c:\inetpub` and also the settings of the application pool in IIS (which set to .NET version 4).

When running the application from within Visual Studio (IIS Express), everything is fine and there is no exception or warning thrown in the Output Window.

How can I find out what's wrong here?

Comment: There should be a log message in the windows event log. Might help point you towards the error.

Comment: Have you checked the account from which you are trying to access in application pool. Check with the application pool --> advance setting --> Identity.

Comment: There are no warnings or errors in the log. @Mayank: The identity should be fine, I also tried switching the identity to an admin user, no change.

Comment: Are you running from visual studio? Have you tried running from "run as admin" your visual studio?